# How to count distinct numbers on the table level and group them

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
name | number
--------------
aaa  | 111
aaa  | 555
bbb  | 222
ccc  | 111
ddd  | 333
eee  | 444
```

and the following:

```
name | country
---------------
aaa  | US
bbb  | UK
ccc  | UK
ddd  | DE
eee  | UK
```

I need to select the number of distinct numbers (distinct on the whole table level), and group theses distinct values based on their countries.

I used the following query:

```
SELECT count(distinct t1.number), t2.country
FROM db.t1
JOIN db.t2
ON t1.name=t2.name
GROUP BY t2.country;
```

The result I get is:

```
3 | UK
2 | US
1 | DE
```

As shown in the first table, I have only 5 distinct numbers. But after the query, I get 6 distinct numbers. This is because the names: `bbb`, `ccc`, `eee` all belongs to UK, but `ccc` does not have a distinct number in the table level (duplicated with the `number` that is associated with `name` `aaa`, but `aaa` in another country).

The question is: How can I query distinct `numbers` on the table level (the current query counts distinct values but in the group level) grouped based on their countries?

Comment: Which country should 111 be counted for, US or UK?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(distinct t1.number), t2.country
FROM (SELECT number, name
      FROM db.t1
      GROUP BY number) t1
JOIN db.t2
ON t1.name=t2.name
GROUP BY t2.country;
```

This picks one of the countries with duplicate numbers arbitrarily.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf684/1)